# How to get user input data from a console program to a c# program?

Tags: c#, c

How to get a user entered inputs in a console application (test app) to a c# program (monitor app)? I have successfully got a string value to my monitor app from the console that is hard corded in the test app. Now I want to allow the user to input a string from the console in test app and I want to capture that user entered string in test app from my monitored app.

Here are the test app and monitor app codes.

test app

```
 using System;


namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test2");
            Console.Write("Enter a string ");
            string txtOne = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(txtOne);
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

monitor app code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace GetStandardOutput
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //
            // Setup the process with the ProcessStartInfo class.
            //
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\Users\erandaka\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe"; // Specify exe name.
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //
            // Start the process.
            //
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                //
                // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
                //
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to retrieve the desired value of the c program.

Use DLLImport, to call the function from your C# program:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i need to get the user entered data through a console window to my c# program.